# Model binding for protected internal set properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, properties, model-binding

In my model classes I have multiple properties that are 'protected internal set'. Once these properties are created they should not be able to be modified. Having said that I am having a hard time creating a model binder that will allow these properties to be set upon creation. What is the best way to proceed in order to be able to set these properties just once?

Comment: Why don't you use view models?

Comment: I would use the view models but it would be too much repetitive code and also the edits and creates share the same view. I need to only bind the data if its a create

Comment: @mmekaiel - it sounds ot me like you're making things a lot harder than you have to.  Just bite the bullet and create specific view models, or forget about using protected properties.

Comment: But then how would I go about not allowing those properties to be changed after they are created?

Comment: @mmekaiel - you can't prevent it, but why would you be changing them anyways?  I agree, it would be nice to do it "right", but when the effort to do that is so great, it's just not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not something you can do automatically.  You'll have to create a unique model binder for each type, and then create the objects using constructor parameters.

Comment: The creating the Unique model binder for these special properties (mostly strings), is the part I am having trouble with. Nothing I am doing seems to correctly bind the data. I would use the view models but it would be too much repetitive code and also the edits and creates share the same view. I need to only bind the data if its a create

Comment: @mmekaiel - as far as I know, you can't limit a model binder to only a specific type of request, it's either all or nothing (Darin might be able to correct me if that's wrong).  So either you do all the work, or none of it (meaning you don't use protected properties).

Comment: If I create a model binder for all the strings would it not work the same whether the properties are regularly set or protected internal set?

Comment: @mmekaiel - I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: @mmekaiel - also, don't fool yourself.  You have to model bind for all types of requests, because when validation fails you need to bind the values that were entered, which means using a special model binder for your case.

Answer (score 1):

I did this using a custom model binder. Not only do I have private setters, but the argument to my MVC action was an interface, and I had no parameter-less constructors (the trifecta!);  none of which work with the default model binder.

In your case, you just have to make a custom model binder for your type. Create a new instance of your class with default values. Then just use Reflection to set the properties on the class. The reflection methods don't care about the property's accessibility. Something like this:

```
// assuming your class looks like this
public class MyClass
{
    public int MyInt { get; private set; }
    public string MyString { get; private set; }

    public MyClass(int myInt, string myString)
    {
        MyInt = myInt;
        MyString = myString;
    }
}

// model binder is like this
public class MyModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,
        ModelBindingContext bindingContext,
        Type modelType)
    {
        // initialize with default values, they will be overwritten
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass(default(int), default(string));
        // get the reflection info on the int property
        PropertyInfo intProperty = typeof(MyClass).GetProperty("MyInt");
        // get the int value from the request
        int myIntValue = int.Parse(bindingContext.ValueProvider
            .GetValue(intProperty.Name).AttemptedValue);
            // btw, attempted value is a string
        // set the property value, SetValue ignores accessibility modifiers
        intProperty.SetValue(myClass, myIntValue, null);
        // do the same stuff for MyString property
        PropertyInfo stringProperty = typeof(MyClass).GetProperty("MyString");
        string myStringValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider
            .GetValue(stringProperty.Name).AttemptedValue;
        stringProperty.SetValue(myClass, myStringValue, null);
        return myClass;
    }
}

// Your controller action is like this
public ActionResult MyAction([ModelBinder(typeof(MyModelBinder))]
                             MyClass myClass)
{
    ...
}
```

I suppose you could have just passed the proper values into the constructor without using reflection to set them:

```
        ...
        int myIntValue = int.Parse(bindingContext.ValueProvider
            .GetValue(intProperty.Name).AttemptedValue);
        string myStringValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider
            .GetValue(stringProperty.Name).AttemptedValue;
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass(myIntValue, myStringValue);
        ...
```

But in case you need to do more, reflection can allow you to get around the access modifier restrictions (for valid infrastructural reasons of course! :D). In my case, I didn't want to write a model binder for every class that could implement the interface, so I used even more reflection to match the class, find a constructor, pass it the default values, then loop through each property on the class and set it from the request values. I have a separate method that validates the message before running actions based off it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you have you protected set method setting a private field only if it is not already set?

```
public string PropertyName
{
  get
  {
     return this.privateField;
  }

  protected set
  {
     if (this.privateField == null)
     {
       this.privateField = value;
     }

  }
}

private string privateField;
```